# Why isn't VS Code respecting TypeScript paths?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, tsconfig, ts-node

In my TypeScript project that's running tests via ts-node and jasmine I have defined some paths in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": [
          "es5",
          "es2015",
          "DOM"
      ],
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "outDir": "./dist/cjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "strict": true,
      "paths": {
            "@common": ["common/index"],
            "@crashes": ["crashes/index"]
      }
  },
  "files": [
      "./src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am able to import via paths `@common` and `@crashes` in my production code, but for some reason VS Code gives me the error `Cannot find module '@common' or its corresponding type declarations.` in my spec.ts files.

How can I get VS Code to recognize TypeScript paths in my tests?

Answer (score 1):

This is because VS Code's intellisense will follow the rules in `tsconfig.json`. In this instance, I was not including the `spec.ts` files in the TypeScript compilation. Additionally, I did not want to include the TypeScript files in my project's build output.

The solution was as follows:

1. Remove the `files` property from `tsconfig.json`
2. Introduce a new `tsconfig.dist.json` that extends `tsconfig.json` and add the `files` property here

```js
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist/cjs",
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/index.ts"
    ]
  }
```

3. Use the new `tsconfig.dist.json` in the publish script

Additionally, once I did all this, I got the following error when I tried to run jasmine tests with ts-node:

```
> ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine --config=spec/support/jasmine.spec.json

Error: Cannot find module '@common'
```

The solution to this error was to install [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) and update my `test` script in `package.json`

```js
{
   "scripts": {
        "test": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine --config=spec/support/jasmine.spec.json"
    }
}
```